# JQuery $.getJSON not working in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, getjson

I am trying to make an ajax call using jquery in my spring MVC based application.

Below is my ajax controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ajax/*")
public class AjaxController extends BaseController {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AjaxController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ICountryService countryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findCountriesByRegionId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Country> findCountriesByRegionId(
            @RequestParam(value = "regionId") int regionId) {
        log.info("finding countries by region id [" + regionId + "]");
        List<Country> countryList = countryService.findByRegionId(regionId);
        return countryList;
    }
```

and Below is my javascript code

```
    function populateCountriesByRegionId(regionId) {
    alert("11");
    $.getJSON("ajax/findCountriesByRegionId", {
        regionId : regionId
    }, function(countryList) {
        alert("2");
        $("#countryId").empty();
        // $("#countryId").html("");
        var options = $("#countryId");
        options.append($("<option />").val('0').text(""));
        $.each(countryList, function() {
            options.append($("<option />").val(this.countryId).text(
                    this.countryName));
        });
    });
}
```

But my controller method is not getting called at all.

When i am on page with url like http://localhost/myApp/emp/new and my ajax url is like ajax/findCountriesByRegionId it gives me error saying no mapping for url myapp/emp/ajax/findCountriesByRegionId.

Why its checking for url  myapp/emp/ajax/findCountriesByRegionId. It should be myapp/ajax/findCountriesByRegionId

When I sue url like /ajax/findCountriesByRegionId (added / at the begining) , nothing happens. No error at all. No conroller invoked.

I wanted to put all my ajax methods in one controller and call those while executing other controller like emp in this case.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first don't use a relative URL in your page. `$.getJSON("/myApp/ajax/findCountriesByRegionId"`,
- second don't have the /* at the end of your mapping at the class level for your controller.  Make it just `/ajax`.
- Third, make sure you can invoke the controller given the url path before trying to hit it with your jquery and make sure the json looks like you expect.  Point chrome to http://localhost/myApp/ajax/findCountriesByRegionId?regionId=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I directly type in url in browser it says The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

Comment: Ok. I could get the proper JSON response on the browser. But it is not invoked by javascript.

Comment: Use Firebug or Developer tools in Chrome/Safari to look at the exact request being made by the getJSON call (e.g. Network tab -> XHR). Also look at what is being returned (404, 500, etc).